# set a request timer in R to pace URL downloads

Tags: r, delay, download-manager

I am using R (curl::curl_download) to retrieve files from the internet/FTP site. Code works great except the site I'm pulling from kicks me out occasionally. Administrator of that site said their system will boot you out if you make more than 1 request/download every 5 seconds. He suggested setting a delay of 5.5 or 6 seconds.

In reviewing the posts on here I see reference to the Sys.sleep command to accomplish this sort of delay. Is this the only option in R? Are their other options?

Thanks!

Joe

Comment: Are you asking if there's code that runs `Sys.sleep(6)` faster?

Comment: It's hard to imagine any scenario where `Sys.sleep()` wouldn't work, given your description.  If it does work, then it seems you've answered yourself.  If it doesn't work for you, please provide more detail.